# How can I easily add a new sender to an existing filter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I would like to easily add a new sender to an existing Gmail filter rule.

For example, if I have an existing filter that includes a list of addresses, I'd like to be able to easily add an additional address.

For now, I have to copy the sender's address, click through the Settings options to get to the filter, open the filter, and paste the new sender into the list.

How can I simplify the process of adding a sender to an existing rule?

[image]

Comment: Again, removed the portion of the question that makes it off-topic.  The question is already framed in such a way that people will still volunteer those solutions if they know of them.  This is commonly done by users (myself included) if there is a gap in a Web App's features that an extension fills.

Answer (score 0):

##### Two Time Savers

Combining a couple of relatively minor changes may not provide a perfect solution but will make it much faster to modify your filter rules and thus a bit less frustrating:

**1.**  Don't click through menus to access settings
    **2.**  Tweak your filter rule syntax to reduce typing

##### 1.   Mouse Less

The most laborious part of the process is accessing the **Filters and Blocked Addresses** tab in Gmail's settings using a mouse. It isn't merely the multiple clicks but also the mouse travel required for each click.  The good news is that you can access the destination directly using its URL: [https://mail.google.com/#settings/filters](https://mail.google.com#settings/filters)

If you are resourceful, you could map the URL to a keyboard shortcut, yet simply adding it to your bookmark bar is easy and will immediately save you time:

- **OLD**
  `move` **mouse >** `click` **Settings >** `move` **mouse >** `click` **See all settings >** `move` **mouse >** `click` **Filters and Blocked Addresses**
- **NEW**
  `move` **mouse >** `click` **[bookmark](https://mail.google.com#settings/filters)**

##### 2.   Type Less

Adding `OR` with each new address adds unnecessary typing.  It is much easier to simply place your insertion point and then paste the address plus a single space, or reverse them depending on where you paste the new address:

- **OLD**
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>   <kbd>SPACE</kbd>   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>   <kbd>SPACE</kbd>
- **NEW**
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>   <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

To enable this, instead of using `OR` between your addresses simply enclose them in braces `{}`:

- **OLD**
  `address1 OR address2 OR address3`
- **NEW**
  `{address1 address2 address3}`